# Javascript não funciona apenas em iOS antigos

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

Olá, este site:
https://www.enmoda.com.br/fale-conosco/, esta funcionando normalmente em todos os navegadores que eu consegui testar, inclusive em um emulador de iPhone com iOS mais recente, porém, em iOS mais antigos (em um iPhone 4 por exemplo), todo o Javascript não funciona.. então, se eu tento enviar o formulário desse link, ao invés do javascript fazer a validação dos campos do formulário, o formulário é enviado.

Acredito que deve ser um erro de javascript só nesses sistemas mais antigos, mas não consigo debugar em iOS.

No Safari do Mac, parece que dá esse Warning:

```
the source list for content security policy directive 'default-src' contains an invalid source: "strict-dynamic". it will be ignored.
```

Mas não impede o site de carregar normalmente no Safari do Mac.

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado.

Comment: Recomendo remover o link para o site e elaborar um [mcve] demonstrando o problema no lugar para não correr o risco de ser punido por spam.

Comment: O problema é que eu não sei onde esta o problema.. no console do Chrome não aparece erro nenhum, em iPhones novos, tudo fica normal... só em iPhones e iPads antigos que não funciona... na verdade, talvez minha dúvida não seja nem para me ajudar com o código, eu preciso de ajuda em como debugar para descobrir o erro nesses dispositivos.. eu até tenho um iPhone 4, mas não tenho um Mac.... existe alguma forma?

Comment: Então não seria interessante perguntar, de fato, isso? E para gerar o [mcve] basta você ir simplificando o seu código. Faça algo como `alert('Ok')` e veja se funciona no iPhone 4. Se não funcionar, já terá o seu exemplo. Se funcionar, vá incrementando o exemplo com o que fez na aplicação até ela parar de funcionar.

Comment: ;-) Farei isso. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugando com os "alerts" que o @Anderson Carlos Woss sugeriu, demorou um bocado, mas consegui encontrar o problema... foram as Arrow Functions do javascript, parece que isso não funciona em nenhum navegador antigo:

```
setTimeout(() => {
     alert('teste');
}, 1000);
```

Precisei trocar por isso:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('teste');
}, 1000);
```

neste link:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions
Tem mais informações de compatibilidade das Arrows Functions... enfim, 2019 ainda não esta preparado para elas, vou parar de usa-las.